# How do I create a Type with multiple generic type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I have been searching of a while now, and have still not been able to find an answer to my question, instead I find answers to Making a Generic Method with multiple Generic Type parameters.

So, this is my problem.  I have an interface `IMyInterface<T1, T2>`and I want to create it as a Type.  Currently I can create the type for `IMyInterface<T>` like this :

```
Type type = typeof(IMyInterface<>).MakeGenericType(genericTypeForMyInterface)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: `Type type = typeof(IMyInterface<>).MakeGenericType(type1, type2);`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[MakeGenericType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes [params Type[]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) as arguments which will be used to construct a generic type. Which means that you could pass any number of arguments.

So you could simply do

```
Type type = typeof(IMyInterface<,>).MakeGenericType(type1, type2);
```

Note you need a comma (,) in between the angular brackets for types with multiple generic type parameters. You need n-1 comma(s) for (n) type parameters. i.e one comma for two type parameter, two commas for three type parameters an so on.

Comment: Post the code which shows that it doesn't work. Also what do you mean by doesn't work? What happens? Compiler error? Runtime error? or..?

Comment: doesn't allow `typeof(IMyInterface<>)` when IMyInterface has two generic types

Comment: @Arran549 Updated my answer. You need to add a comma inside the angular brackets. If that still doesn't works please explain what happens, what error you get etc.

Comment: Excellent - Many thanks that works. Cheers for all your help :)